# Sveltekit VITE v3.0.2 localhost changed from 3000 to 5173

Tags: localhost, vite, sveltekit

July 20th 2022 New Sveltekit project created by npm init svelte@next. Before today all sveltekit projects were run in dev mode on localhost:3000. This current project is running on localhost:5173 which makes it difficult as supabase returns responses to localhost:3000 by default.
I have tried changing the package.json as in https://www.cloudhadoop.com/svelte-change-port/
That did not work.
I have tried changing the Vite server options as in https://main.vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-host
That didn't work either.
Has anyone got a foolproof easy way of getting new Sveltekit projects on localhost:3000?
Many thanks

Comment: Just set `server.port` ?

Comment: after much searching I found that in the new sveltekit package.json instead of "dev": "svelte-kit dev" it now has "dev": "vite dev" so I modified the advice in https://www.cloudhadoop.com/svelte-change-port/ and changed it to "dev": "vite dev --port 3000" and lo-and-behold it did run the dev server on localhost:3000.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from [1.0.0-next.359](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/master/packages/kit/CHANGELOG.md#100-next359), SvelteKit switched to Vite CLI for `dev`, `build`, and `preview` commands.

Therefore, the default port changed to `5173`, which is the default value of the Vite `server.port`.

You can change the port value in `vite.config.js` as well, a file which is now required.

Reference [Vite / Config / Server Options](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

when yarn using --port

such as

```
yarn dev --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000
```

careful about the security issue. only for dev